# C# Windows Application Form and Data base

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, forms

I am loading elements (a row) from a database in a list. Which technique should I use to update the list when a new entry is added in that table ( SQL database) so that the lists updates and if I have selected an element from the list it won`t get deselected (like Outlook when new mails are received and you have a mail selected ).

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you are trying to do? Is this a Windows Forms application you're talking about?

Comment: Also, more information about the enrty added?  Is the enrty added from the program? or in the database itself?  Which list should be updated?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is a bit vague and it will be hard to answer. I suggest you try to give an example of what you've tried so far, or even just a bit more detail of what you'd like to achieve. You could also read these guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask which were written to help newcomers get good answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dealing with simple database transactions, I would recommend a foray into the [BindingSource Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h974h4y2.aspx). The BindingSource component can take care of creating, reading, updating and deleting things so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your rows have a unique identifier. You can store this Id before you add the new row, and after it's added you can search the list with the stored Id to re-select that row.

(Actually it would be wiser to store the row handle and re-selecting it directly with the handle. But it wouldn't work if your grid creates new row objects to display the updated list. Since I don't know how you bind your data, I cannot say this would work for sure.)